# What is a good approach to be able setting function to object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

```
//namespace
if (!window.SlidePanel) {
    window.SlidePanel = (function () {
        var SlidePanel = {};

        return SlidePanel;
    })();
}   

SlidePanel.panel = function (el) {
    this.$ = el;
}
SlidePanel.panel.prototype = {
    insert: function () {
    },
    show: function () {
    },
    hide: function () {
    }        
}

SlidePanel.up = new SlidePanel.panel($('div#up-panel'));
SlidePanel.bottom = new SlidePanel.panel($('div#bottom-panel'));
SlidePanel.left = new SlidePanel.panel($('div#left-panel'));
SlidePanel.right = new SlidePanel.panel($('div#right-panel'));
```

I want to be able to set `show` and `hide` functions in some place of code. I thought to add `setShowFn` and `setHideFn` function to `SlidePanel.panel.prototype` like this

```
  SlidePanel.panel.prototype = {
        ...
        setShowFn: function (fn) {
            this.show = fn;
        },
        setHideFn: function (fn) {
            this.hide = fn;
        }
  }
```

Is this a good approach or there is more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Looks fine to me.  Although personally I would not bother with the setters since JavaScript has no concept of private/protected members anyways.  If I wanted to override `show()` and `hide()` on a given `SlidePanel` instance I would just assign them directly, like `myPanel.show = someOtherFunction;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to override the `show` or `hide` function on just one instance of a `SlidePanel.panel`, you're free to just update that instance:

```
SlidePanel.up.show = function() { /* ... */ };
```

That breaks the inheritance of `show` for that specific instance, without changing any other instances that still use the `show` property from the prototype.

If you want to update `show` for *all* instances that are using the inherited version, you can do this at any time:

```
SlidePanel.panel.prototype.show = function() { /* ... */ };
```

...since the instances have a reference back to the prototype, and so changes to the prototype happen "live." Note that any instance on which you've done the first example above will be unaffected, because it's not using the version of `show` from the prototype anymore.

And yes, you're free to encapsulate this in your `setShowFn` and `setHideFn` functions if you want to; just be aware that there's nothing other than convention/documentation preventing code from assigning to the properties directly even if you do.

Comment: But, in this way I'll have 2 `show`. Is this ok? And `SlidePanel` doesn't have `show`

Comment: @theateist: That's right, you'll end up with a `show` function you use for most panels via the prototype, and a different `show` function you use for certain instances. That's fine in terms of JavaScript; it's up to you whether it's fine for your proj. On the second thing, I've updated the answer to put `.panel` where it should be, I missed that it was a separate constructor function. (FWIW, the overwhelming convention in JavaScript is to use initial caps for constructor functions, e.g. `SlidePanel.Panel` rather than `SlidePanel.panel`. It's just convention, but it's a very well-observed one.)